# SSRS Column Visibility

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a SSRS table that i have created with SharePoint data source. I have more than 30 column with yes and no value in that SharePoint list. I am trying to count the yes values, and then display top 10 columns on this SSRS report. 
I am able to pull the true count but however not able to only show top ten.
[image]
Should i create a new table to pull information from this table on the same report?

---

How would you do it if L1, L2, L3, etc... were not from one field but are all different fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same scenario. 
My Approach: Created custom function , which give the index of group of rows. And using the row visibility function, i have hidden all the rows greater then 10 index.

1) Custom Function:

```
Dim Counter as integer=0
public function getGroupCounter() as Integer
 Counter=Counter+1
 return Counter
end function
```

2) Set Row visibility
In the row visibility section, have added the following expression:

```
=IIf(Code.getGroupCounter() <= 10 ,False, True)
```

3) Group sort behaviour
Change the sorting behaviour of the group

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's very elegant, but it does  seem effective

Comment: this has been a while but where do you put the custom action. i created this report on ssrs builder not on visual studio.

Comment: Go to report property -> Code section

Comment: Thank you Ravindra, i was able to hide rows with row visiblity.